# Hibernate - unexpected token: lower

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I have to get all registers in my DB (PostgreSQL) with **case-insesitive**. I have tried with criteria but the ***ignoreCase()*** is not working for me (I'm using Hibernate 3.6).

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.eq(TABLECODEID, tableCodeID).ignoreCase());
```

I have also tried to use the ***ilike*** method but still doesn't work.

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike(TABLECODEID, tableCodeID));
```

And this version too:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike(TABLECODEID, tableCodeID, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

So now I'm getting this error when I try to create a query in Hibernate with HQL:

```
unexpected token: lower near line 1, column 81
```

My code looks like this:

```
StringBuffer queryString = new StringBuffer()
                    .append("from ListItem li ")
                    .append("where lower(li.tableCodeId) like :tableCodeId");

Query query = session.createQuery(queryString.toString());
query.setParameter("tableCodeId", tableCodeID.toLowerCase());

List<ListItem> listItemListAux = query.list();
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used HQL and the problem was I was attacking the entity in the **lower(li.tableCodeId)** function, I had to use the DB column name **lower(tablecodeid)**

Answer (score 0):

You should resolve in this way, the `MatchMode.ANYWHERE` will do the trick:

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike(TABLECODEID, tableCodeID, MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
```

Comment: I have tried it right now and keeps the same... T_T Thank you for your time.